# How can I change the width of the container div in bootstrap onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Asp.Net MVC project.
In my _Layout.cshtml I am using container class for my main container div:

```
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

However, for one of my page I have a button that would allow expand the size of the container to full screen width and back (user will be able to toggle the width from default to full screen width and vice versa).

the container-fluid class kind of doing the same think, but I need to to it on-the-fly on button click. How can I do that? Moreover, is there any way to change the width only for the specific view not effecting other pages (since the container is defined in _layout.cshtml it would effect other views as well)?

Comment: You want to use vanilla javascript (or jquery) to remove the `container` class from that element, and add `container-fluid` in its place. Swap back and forth on button click.

Comment: Swapping the class did the trick but it is not perfect. For some reason the page doesn't responds to the change right away ... any thought about it?

Answer (score 1):

For all containers:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    $(".container").toggleClass("container-fluid");
});
```

For only the parent `.container` of the button clicked

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(".container").toggleClass("container-fluid");
});
```

You can swap out `container-fluid` for a class of your choice if you want to set it to a specific style outside of the provided bootstrap classes.

Comment: It is working somewhat. But having an issue updating the page. It expansion and contraction doesn't happen right away. Is there a method to force the page/container apply the new css? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some experiment, I found that following code just works fine for me:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").className = "new_css_class_name";
```

It force the document update the view instantly, which was a problem in case of above presented solution.